# Turn custom Woocommerce shortcodes into php code for archive-product.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Tl;dr: I want to use similar functionality in WC shortcodes but within the WC shop page.

I have many custom Woocommerce shortcodes I have created. I use them throughout non-shop pages.
E.g:

```
function displayProductIngredients($item) {

$product = wc_get_product($item['id']);
return $product->get_attribute( 'ingredients' );
}

add_shortcode('product_ingredients', 'displayProductIngredients');
```

I would like to use them in the archive-product.php page too.
E.g. in the example this shortcode adds the content of the "ingredients" attribute. How can the same be added for each new product added?

Is this just a case of moving around some of the php? If so, how might it look?

Thank you very much.